# ps x shows weird command: -f html/index.php

Tags: php, linux, apache

Just went to check one of my homepages and was greeted by the message: "CGIWrap Error: Real UID could not be changed!". Went in via SSH and tried "ps x" which showed me tons of processes that that where just "-f " and the path to index.php or some other site. After killing all processes everything went back to normal.

Anyone know what that is? Google did not help at all.

Comment: you should try posting this question on http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: thanks, I just went and posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-f file.php
```

is a bash command that checks that a file exists and is a regular file.
However, I cannot give you a reason for having tons of processes like this and those blocking your cgi.